# How to format/serialize asynchronous API callback responses, when inside the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am exposing an API that responds asynchronously to certain requests. This is possible, as the client appends a callback_url in their request, to which the asynchronous action will send the result when it completes.

Problem is, the action completes while inside a model, which makes it tricky to keep a clear seperation of concerns, as I usually handle stiching together JSON responses in the controller using ActiveModelSerializer.

Any advice on how to approach this in an idiomatic way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to extract the outgoing callback response into a separate service (called from within the model) and place that service on an asynchronous queue.

This service should be as generic as possible. Any logic that relates to building/sending/logging outgoing responses would then be contained within the service, and is separated out of the Model.

I would then wrap the service call in an asynchronous priority queue system, such as [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). This would allow the Model to do its thing before handing the response off to the service for asynchronous execution.

The benefit to using a queue system is that should anything prevent the response from being posted it will not 'freeze' the Model whilst executing. Bottom line; the Model can hand the response over to the queue and forget about the details of sending the response.

Ryan B. himself says (pro account required):

- [OlderRailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects?view=comments)